# Windows 7 Recent Places behaviour

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, history

Apparently it only lists the folders or places when you open a file or perform an action inside it. If you visit a folder and move back or close the explorer without opening any file inside it, it will not be recorded under Recent Places. Is there a way to change this behaviour so even folders i visit are added there?

If not can you suggest programs that perform the same function and integrate with explorer to add link similar to Recent Places, and display list of recently visited folders?

Not to be confused with Recent Items that displays recently opened files in start menu!